# MVC Label with html entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I have some label text with html entity characters e.g. `&nbsp;` (and `&eacute;` etc) which when passed to `Html.Label` are coming out as `&amp;nbsp;` for example. What is the best way to get back `&nbsp;` from the helper?

**Edit:** The text is coming from a localized resource, so for the case `Html.Label("myinput", labelText)` the `labelText` is unknown and may or may not contain entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's a really old question, however it was never answered properly and I was looking for an answer to it.

**The solution for this case is:**

```
@Html.Label("myinput", HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&hellip;yet another label"))
```

or if you are using model:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.SomeProperty,HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&hellip;yet another label"))
```

of course if your label string does not contain any html entities, it will render just fine, so it covers your case with dynamic label:

```
@Html.Label("myinput", labelText)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it's just simpler to write pure html

```
<label for="myinput">This is text&nbsp;</label>
```

Comment: I don't think this is an option in my case, as the text is coming from a localized resource so when I'm doing `Html.Label("myinput", labelText)` I'm not aware if there are entities or not, or even if what the text is. Thanks tho.